# Using C++20 in the nvcc compiler for cuda

Tags: cuda, c++20, nvcc

I'm trying to use the `std::countr_zero()` function from the `<bitset>` library, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to configure my nvcc compiler as I'm sure it's not using the C++20 version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CUDA 12 and above [supports the C++20 standard](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-toolkit-12-0-released-for-general-availability/).

You can find answers to your question more generally by checking [Nvidia's standards C++ language support docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support) and [this compiler support for language features page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

In visual studio you can enable c++20 support by adding the command line option `--std c++20` (Note no `=`) to the CUDA C/C++ Command line options in your project options.

[image]